# Do Chrome Apps support badges (red bubble) in the app icon?

Tags: google-chrome-app

I was very surprised to not find any API endpoint for showing badges (red bubble) on app icons. I was expecting something similar to [browser action badges](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#method-setBadgeText) - which has been available for extensions for a long time. I imagine it would look something such as:

```
chrome.app.setBadgeText({
  text: ""
});
```

I see this has already been discussed in issues ([311878](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=311878), [239575](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=239575), [143219](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=143219)), but suspect it might have gone a bit cold. [This diff](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/browser/ui/cocoa/apps/native_app_window_cocoa.mm?r1=250086&r2=250085&pathrev=250086) is promising, but does anyone have any other insight or know when it's planned to be completed?

Answer (score 0):

The bug is probably the best place to get info about it. As mentioned there it has gone a bit cold as we have some higher priorities, but I expect we'll get to it when time permits.

Comment: Any progress on this?